# Does the area of a circle approximates $\pi r^2$ or IS it $\pi r^2$?

Tags: calculus, limits, circles, area

So I've been watching YouTube videos (3Blue1Brown: https://youtu.be/WUvTyaaNkzM
Khanacademy:https://youtu.be/a2L27dTOyHk )
about the geometrical explanation of the area of a circle.
Both of these explanations seem to conclude that as a quantity ($n$ or $dr$) approaches infinity so does the area of a circle approaches
the number : $\pi r^2$.  So shouldn't we say that the area of a circle is approximately $\pi r^2$ rather than IT'S $\pi r^2$?

Comment: The limit (if it exists) is an exact value, not just an approximation. So, a circle with radius $r$ has not just approximately area $\pi\cdot r^2$ , it has exactly this area.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: As some quantity approaches to infinity the area of corresponding geometrical figure (which is not a circle) approaches $\pi r^2$. The geometrical figure itself starts to look more and more like a circle as $n\to\infty $.

Comment: If you think the area is anything other than exactly $\pi r^2$, the linked techniques produce some approximation that guarantees the area is even closer to $\pi r^2$, forcing a contradiction.

Answer (score 6):

In those videos the circle is approximated by shapes which *are not* themselves circles. So saying that the area of the circle approaches $\pi r^2$ is simply wrong. The areas of the simpler shapes are approaching the area of the circle. And their areas are approaching $\pi r^2$. If the thing they are approaching is the area of the circle, and the thing they are approaching is $\pi r^2$, then basic logic dictates that $\pi r^2$ is the area of the circle.

Consider this: The place I'm walking towards is my place of residence. And I'm walking towards 123 example street. So my place of residence is 123 example street. Even though *I* am not at 123 example street during the process of walking there. In the same way, the approximate areas *are not* the real area. But they go towards the real area, which is $\pi r^2$.

Comment: +1 I saw your answer after adding a comment to question. My comment is based on essentially the same idea  as given in your answer. If you wish I can delete my comment.

Answer (score 4):

The area of a circle *is* $\pi r^2$. The videos you point out discuss (somewhat heuristically) successive approximations to the circle whose areas approach that of the circle.